# Difference between sf::st_buffer and terra::buffer on R: diameter and radius

Tags: r, buffer, r-sf, terra

I'm getting confused with the usage of `st_buffer` from package `sf` and `buffer` from `terra` package on R.

I'm creating buffers around points and when using `sf::st_buffer` I understand I need to use the **radius** of the buffer in the argument `dist` BUT when using `terra::buffer` I need to specify the **diameter** of the buffer in the argument `width`.

Is this correct?

I´ve checked here for `sf::st_buffer`, argument `dist`: https://rdrr.io/r/stats/dist.html

and here for `terra::buffer`, argument `width`: https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/width.html

Answer (score 9):

A buffer is a distance from an object. In that general sense it is neither a radius nor a diameter.

When you create a buffer around a point, the buffer is a circle, and the buffer distance (width) is equivalent to the radius of that circle.

This does not apply for buffers around lines, polygons or raster cells.

Some illustrative code with `terra`

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(cbind(0,0), crs="+proj=utm +zone=1")
b <- buffer(v, 1)
ext(b)
#SpatExtent : -1, 1, -1, 1 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

v <- vect(cbind(0,0), crs="+proj=longlat")
# 1 degree at equator is ~ 111 km
b <- buffer(v, 111000)
round(ext(b), 2)
#SpatExtent : -1, 1, -1, 1 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

The below shows buffers for longitude/latitude points at different latitudes. And these buffers *are* circles, all with the same radius, even though that is hard to see with the distortion from flattening the earth.

```
v <- vect(cbind(0, seq(0, 80, 15)), crs="+proj=longlat")
b <- buffer(v, 1100000)
plot(b, asp=1, border=rainbow(8), lwd=2)
points(v)
```

[image]

Comment: What are x and y axis in your picture? longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 6):

I believe that on theoretic level the correct answer is the one by @robert-hijmans (circular buffer around a point being only a special case of a generic buffer object).

I would like to point out another practical difference though: for unprojected coordinates `{sf}` uses the S2 library by Google. the S2 library makes a somewhat different set of shortcuts and assumptions than GEOS, and produces a different looking buffer.

Consider this example, and note how different (kind of like pixellated) the red buffer is.

```
library(nominatimlite)
library(sf)
library(terra)

a_point <- geo_lite_sf("Royal Observatory, Greenwich")

st_crs(a_point) # WGS84
# Coordinate Reference System:
#   User input: WGS 84 
#   wkt:
# GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
#     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#         AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
#             ORDER[1],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#         AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
#             ORDER[2],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#     ID["EPSG",4326]]

st_is_longlat(a_point) # this is important! S2 will be used.
# [1] TRUE


sf_buffer <- a_point |>
  st_buffer(dist = 500) |>
  st_geometry()

terra_buffer <- a_point |>
  vect() |>
  buffer(width = 500)

plot(sf_buffer, border = "red")
plot(terra_buffer, border = "blue", add = T)
```

[image: red and blue buffers]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of `terra` (and more or less never used it), but I think both functions require the radius of the buffer:

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(terra)
#> terra version 1.4.11

# data
point_sf <- st_as_sfc("POINT (0 0)", crs="+proj=merc")
point_terra <- vect("POINT (0 0)", crs="+proj=merc")

# buffer
buffer_sf <- st_buffer(point_sf, dist = 5)
buffer_terra <- buffer(point_terra, width = 5)

# plot
plot(buffer_sf, axes = TRUE, lwd = 10)
plot(buffer_terra, border = "red", add = TRUE, lwd = 3.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>