# Create buffers in km units for global point dataset in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I'm new to using spatial data so this probably seems like a very simple question, but something I'm struggling to get my head around.

I have a global dataset of sample sites and corresponding coordinates. I am using st_buffer in the sf package to create buffers of different sizes around these points. However, I need these buffers to be in km, for example 2,10,50 km radius, rather than in the units of the CRS projection (currently in long/lat, WGS84). As I understand it, UTM is the only planar projection, but does this mean I have to split my global dataset into each of the UTM zones before converting to UTM, and then create the buffers for each of these separately?

Is it possible to then convert the buffers back to my previous CRS projection?

Thank you!

Comment: "UTM is the only planar projection" is not correct. Essentially all projections are planar. In contrast, longitude/latitude is angular. If the crs of your data is angular, it is better to use that to compute distances (including buffers), because projecting the data would distort.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to step out of the comfort of WGS84 to do a metric buffer; most of the tools are ready to combine longlat CRS with a metric definition of distance (it is a *very* common use case).

When buffering in WGS84 I kind of prefer `terra::buffer()` to `sf::st_buffer()` as it is likely to produce a smoother shape - the S2 functions that work under the hood of unprojected `{sf}` do not work [smooth enough for me and the outcome is somewhat grainy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70152564/7756889). But I digress...

Consider this piece of code, what it does is:

- looks up the coordinates of a semi random landmark (Greenwich Observatory in London)
- buffers it by 25 kilometers
- displays the result

Note how the [terra documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/buffer.html) states that the buffer is in meters for unprojected coordinates.

```
library(nominatimlite)
library(sf)
library(terra)

a_point <- geo_lite_sf("Royal Observatory, Greenwich")

st_crs(a_point) # WGS84

terra_buffer <- a_point |>
  vect() |>
  buffer(width = 25000) %>% # 25 kilometers
  st_as_sf()

mapview::mapview(terra_buffer)
```

[image]

Comment: You motivate the use of `terra::buffer()`  over `sf::st_buffer()` due to some "kind of prefer reasons", but it seems the main reason is that `sf::st_buffer()` will expect arc-degree `dist` with a WGS84 data? Or can you give meter dist to `sf::st_buffer()`? Thanks!

Comment: You can give metric radius to `sf` buffer - do give it a try! - but it will be routed via `s2` and it will be visually kind of ugly. Which is my main issue with it... For purposes of calculation it should be roughly equivalent / even if the  terra` buffer is somewhat more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: For comparison of the two buffers have a look at this earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/a/70152564/7756889

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I would suggest referencing to that other post in your answer here :-)