# draw figures on a map with `sf`

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, spatstat

I am struggling to find a systematic way to convert coordinates and geometries to km.
Let's say I have a `.shp` file, which I read with `st_read`. I want to draw a circle of radius 10 kms around a city. I know the coordinates of the city in latitude and longitude, so I can convert to  km with:

```
  y = 111.2 * latitude
  x = 111.2 * longitude * cos(pi / 130* latitude)
```

And then define a circle centered in `x,y`. Now I can easily draw the circle with `plot.owin {spatstat.geom}`, but, how can I plot is onto the geometry of the `.shp` file? Can I use `st_crs` to set the coordinates of the circle to the reference system of the original map (and how)?

Comment: If you just need circles around points, `sf::st_buffer()` should work.  The edges can be a bit ragged, but there is a `terra` workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73506577/7547327

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Can I set the units in `sf::st_buffer()`, say km or meters?

Comment: You can use the `units` package, or set the crs to one with the correct units for the area of the globe.